# rewrite just one parameter in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite:

`http://mystagingsite.com/website/?page_id=7&id=63&r_id=1-502ba82b9e926&event_id=1&attendee_action=post_payment&form_action=payment&type=paypal`

into

`http://mystagingsite.com/website/?page_id=102&id=63&r_id=1-502ba82b9e926&event_id=1&attendee_action=post_payment&form_action=payment&type=paypal`

So the page_id parameter needs to change....I need to send the user visiting the first url to the second url. All I need to change is the id parameter...all other params need to be preserved.

I'm trying this:

```
RewriteRule http://mystagingsite.com/website/?page_id=7 http://mystagingsite.com/website/?page_id=102  [QSA]
```

but it doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against query strings (everything after the **`?`**) or the protocol/host (the `http://mystagingsite.com`) in a rewrite rule, you'll have to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` and `%{HTTP_HOST}` variables in a rewrite condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mystagingsite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)page_id=7&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^website/$ /website/?%1page_id=102&%2 [L]
```

A bit of confusion though. In your question, you said you wanted `page_id=7` rewritten to `page_id=102`, but in your example, you have `63` rewritten to `102`.

Comment: Hi Jon, Many thanks. I've learnt a lot from that! Edited the error in the example now